# Disable mongoid belongs_to association validation

Tags: ruby-on-rails, mongoid

A have two mongoid models with a simple has_many/belongs_to relationship between them:

```
class Lot
  include Mongoid::Document
  has_many :journal_items
end

class JournalItem
  include Mongoid::Document
  belongs_to :lot
end
```

The issue is that I can't create a `JournalItem` without a `Lot` as it seems that mongoid adds a non-null validation on the `JournalItem.lot_id` by default.

```
JournalItem.create!
# raises validation error "Lot can't be blank"
```

How can I disable it?

I use the mongoid master with Rails 5.

Answer (score 34, accepted):

Ok, I've figured it out — mongoid associations have the `optional` option, which doesn't seem to be documented very well.

So it should be:

```
class JournalItem
  include Mongoid::Document
  belongs_to :lot, optional: true
end
```

Answer (score 8):

In Rails 5 **belongs_to** will default to required: true (see [rails/rails/pull/18937](https://github.com/rails/rails/pull/18937))

So now required: true is deprecated:

```
belongs_to :company, required: true # deprecated => `required: true`
```

To disable this option on ActiveRecord based apps you should create an initializer to explicitly configure the new behavior for the app:

```
# config/initializers/active_record_belongs_to_required_by_default.rb

Rails.application.config.active_record.belongs_to_required_by_default = true
```

And for every belongs_to relation that is not required, just add optional: true.

```
belongs_to :company, optional: true
```

And for Mongoid +6.0 you will need to add this option in your Mongoid initializer :

```
# config/initializers/mongoid.rb
Mongoid::Config.belongs_to_required_by_default = false
```